# loading highcharts with data from database

Tags: highcharts

Hi i am new to highcharts and zend. i installed highcharts in my zend view and able to draw a chart with some dummy data. now i want to create a chart with data from my database. my data contains the weight of the user and the date of weight measurement.

```
    x axis will be the weight of the user
    y axis will be the date of weight measurement
```

i have the database ready but i don't have any idea about how to create the chart from that data in my database. 
thanks.

Comment: it will be easier to get answers to this question if you provide some code.

Comment: Did my answer help you at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often the x axis is used for the time value, but you can invert the chart by setting the `inverted` property to `true` to swap places for x and y axes (essentially making the time axis vertical instead of horizontal):

```
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'spline',
    inverted: true   // <== inverted chart
},

xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
},

series: [{
    data: [[Date.UTC(2011, 0, 1), 69.9],
          [Date.UTC(2011, 0, 2), 71.5],
          [Date.UTC(2011, 0, 3), 76.4],
          [Date.UTC(2011, 0, 4), 81.5],
          [Date.UTC(2011, 0, 5), 80.4]]
}]
```

I made an example for you on jsfiddle showing this: http://jsfiddle.net/emWm7/

Reference doc: http://www.highcharts.com/ref/index.php#chart--inverted

Answer (score -1):

I have two code samples you can use. One is generating tab-separated values from your table. The other is generating JSON string from your table.

Tab-separated values example [here](http://blueflame-software.com/blog/using-highcharts-with-php-and-mysql/).

JSON example [here](http://blueflame-software.com/blog/how-to-load-mysql-results-to-highcharts-using-json/).